# Detect server automatically

Tags: php, node.js, electron, xampp

Assuming I have an Electron APP which is a client. And a Server PHP running in Xampp within the local network.

How would you implement an auto-detect server without knowing the IP Address?

For example, when you open the electron app it should automatically detect the server within the local network.

I was thinking maybe in my app, I would identify the current ip address, extract the network id e.g. `192.168.0` and then from 1-255 send a request and if any of it response `I-AM-THE-SERVER` then that is the server. But then this will be a time consuming task.

Comment: Look into zero-config protocols, local network broadcasts etc. There are many approaches and already standardised mechanisms.

Comment: I did something similar with ARP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol